# Making single installer for addins of multiple Outlook versions

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am making outlook addins separately for Outlook 2003, 2007, 2010. I want to write a single installer that can install the addin basing on which outlook version is being used. How to do that? Because WebEx seem to be doing that, with out asking for which version it has installed in my word, excel, outlook. If there is a way please provide reference to it.

Also please share any alternative approaches if you are aware of.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a detailed answer for you but here is a possible path for you to follow:

1. Use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) to create your installer. This will give you a lot of flexibility.
2. Package all of your VSTOs (2003, 2007, 2010) with the installer.
3. In the "Install" section of your .nsi file determine which version of Outlook is installed. One easy way (though I'm not sure of its reliability) is to check for the existence of the appropriate registry key under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office. For example the existence of a key named "14.0" should mean that Office 2010 is installed.
4. Now that you know the version of Outlook that is installed, install the appropriate VSTO.